# Expectation and median (Jensen’s inequality) of spacial functions

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

Let’s have a 1-Lipschitz function $f:S^n \to \mathbb{R}$, where $S^n$ is equipped with the geodesic distance $d$ and with the uniform measure $\mu$.

How can I show that such an $f$ satisfies Jensen’s inequality:
$(\int_{S^n} f d\mu)^2 \leq {\int_{S^n} f^2 d\mu}$?

In addition, is it true that in such a case we have $\sqrt{\int_{S^n} f^2 d\mu} \leq m$ where $m$ is the unique number satisfying $\mu(f \geq m) \geq 0.5,  \space \mu(f \leq m) \geq 0.5$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first inequality is called Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, rather than Jensen inequality. Its proof is simple and very general: one considers $g=(f-a)^2$ with $a=\int\limits_{S_n}f\,\mathrm d\mu$. Then $g\geqslant0$ everywhere hence $\int\limits_{S_n}g\,\mathrm d\mu\geqslant0$. Expanding this by linearity and using the fact that the mass of $\mu$ is $1$ yields the result.

The second inequality you suggest is odd. If $f(x)=x_1-1$, then $m=-1$, which ruins every chance to get a nonnegative quantity $\leqslant m$. More generally, $ \sqrt{ \int\limits_{S^n} f^2\,\mathrm d\mu } \geqslant \int\limits_{S^n} f\,\mathrm d\mu$ and, as soon as $f$ is symmetric around one of its medians $m$, the RHS is $m$. To sum up, no comparison can exist, and if one existed, it would be the opposite of the one you suggest.